# Tesla coil charging the battery with AC?

Tags: transformer

[image]

For Tesla coil, eventually the capacitor voltage becomes so high that the air in the spark gap is unable to hold-off the high electric field and breakdown occurs.

But usually from what I know DC can charge up the capacitor, not AC. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The capacitor eventually reaches an AC peak voltage that is enough for the spark gap to arc-over. When AC is initially applied, L1 and Cp form a series resonant tuned circuit.

At this point the effect of Lp is insignificant to L1 i.e. L1 dominates so ignore this for now.

The AC voltage across Cp starts low and builds and builds rising positively and negatively with the AC power supply frequency. Eventually the peak voltage across Cp (positive or negative) is enough to cause an arc on the spark gap.

This massive dV/dt change in C pushes through a really big current into Lp and this ultimately causes the high voltage stuff we all love (or not)!

Comment: Does this mean that the breaking rate of the circuit is twice the line frequency? The audible pulsing of the tesla coil would occur at 120hz? Can we assume that the spark gap only fires once per half cycle?

Comment: @rstif350 I don't think that can be assumed. It may take several 50/60 Hz cycles to build up capacitor amplitude before the primary spark gap operates. The discharge may last more than one cycle of AC too. You can't even say that the capacitor will be at its positive peak when the initial spark happens.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that a capacitor charges up (over several cycles) until the voltage across the spark gap reaches breakdown. But for that kind of behavior there would need to be a diode. There is no diode here.

What happens is that Cs and Ls form a resonator circuit which is excited by and receives energy from Lp. Lp, Cp with L1 and T1 also form a resonator with a spark gap. The spark gap when it breaks down connects Cp in parallel with Lp making them discharge (part of) their energy in the  Cs, Ls resonator.

A resonator can also be charged, compare it to a children's swing, you can "charge" it by applying a small amount of energy at the correct time. Most of the energy remains in the resonator but excitation increases even with small amounts of energy added.

In a resonator the energy goes back and forth between the capacitor and the coil.